# Need help in Finding MaxDate and MinDate in sql server based or condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in the following form

```
id  First service date  Last service date
1   6/19/2006           6/19/2006
1   7/3/2006            7/3/2006
1   7/19/2006           7/19/2006
1   9/10/2007           9/10/2007
1   9/25/2007           9/25/2007
2   4/3/2007            4/3/2007
2   7/9/2007            7/9/2007
2   10/1/2007           5/19/2008
2   1/15/2008           1/15/2008
2   2/13/2008           2/13/2008
2   3/7/2008            3/7/2008
3   5/9/2006            5/9/2006
3   5/15/2006           5/15/2006
3   6/22/2006           6/22/2006
3   10/3/2006           10/3/2006
```

I need to find the Minimum service date and Maximum service date for each id . The condition imposed is that if there is a gap of more than 90 days between each service then the most recent first date of service would be the minimum service date.

So the result I am expecting is

```
ID  Minimum date of service     Max date of service
1   9/10/2007                   9/25/2007
2   7/9/2007                    5/19/2008
3   10/3/2006                   10/3/2006
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the "service_date" field, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is date type. Here is the query I tried but getting wrong answer SELECT
m.ID,
MIN(t.FirstServiceDate) AS MinDate,
m.MaxDate
FROM (
 SELECT 
 ID,
 MAX(LastServiceDate) AS MaxDate
 FROM #Temp
 GROUP BY ID) AS m
INNER JOIN #Temp t ON m.ID = t.ID AND m.MaxDate <= DATEADD(dd, 90, t.FirstServiceDate)
GROUP BY m.ID, m.MaxDate

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
select t1.id, min(t2.firstdate), max(t2.lastdate)
from yourTable t1
inner join yourTable t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    and datediff(day, t1.firstdate, t2.firstdate) > 90
group by t1.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66b05/2)

Comment: @user1405838 did you see the SQL Fiddle demo?  the test data that you provided seems to be working.  Can you give a different sample? Or explain the result you received?

Comment: bluefeet , it is working for the data i provided but for some data I am getting wrong result

Comment: Like for this dataset:id first_service last_service
1 6/19/2006 6/19/2006
1 7/3/2006 7/3/2006
1 7/19/2006 7/19/2006
1 7/19/2006 12/16/2006
1 9/1/2006 9/1/2006
1 10/11/2006 10/11/2006
1 10/26/2006 10/26/2006
1 11/21/2006 11/21/2006
1 12/5/2006 12/5/2006
1 12/15/2006 12/16/2006
1 12/15/2006 12/18/2006
1 6/14/2007 6/14/2007
1 8/21/2007 8/21/2007
1 8/21/2007 11/5/2007
1 8/24/2007 8/24/2007
1 9/4/2007 9/4/2007
1 9/5/2007 9/5/2007
1 9/10/2007 9/10/2007
1 9/25/2007 9/25/2007
1 10/23/2007 10/23/2007
1 10/24/2007 10/24/2007
1 11/5/2007 11/8/2007
1 3/20/2008 3/20/2008

Comment: I am getting this result:id (No column name) (No column name)
1 2006-10-11 2008-03-20

Comment: and what is the result you want to get?

Comment: sorry i want to get 1 3/20/2008 3/20/2008

Comment: @user1405838 Did you try using `max(t2.firstdate)` to see if that gives you the right result?